# Approximating the number of lattice points on a sphere

Tags: physics, diophantine-equations, approximation

When deriving the [Rayleigh-Jeans law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/rayj.html) in physics, one must count the number of solutions $(a,b,c)$ to the Diophantine equation
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=R^2.$$
The source I have linked approximates the number of integer solutions as the volume of the sphere with radius $R$ (so that there are approximately $\frac{4\pi}{3}R^3$ solutions).

It is not clear to me why this approximation works. The volume provides us with the number of "unit cubes" one can fit inside the sphere. How is there (almost) a bijection between these unit cubes inside the sphere and lattice points on the sphere?

Comment: Well, obviously, this includes the number of points on the sphere _and on all smaller spheres_.

Comment: I seem to be misunderstanding something; the page you link seems to claim that the number of positive solutions is in the order of $\tfrac{2\pi}{3}R^3$, which is greater than $2R^3$. But the number of triplets of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2\leq R^2$ is strictly (and *much*) smaller than $R^3$, as clearly $a,b,c<R$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes, if we assume that the the lattice points are "uniformly distributed" in a sense then the volume of the sphere is approximately the number of lattice points on the sphere and all smaller spheres. But what about the number of lattice points just on the original sphere?

Comment: @Servaes The volume (which is on the order of $R^3$) should indirectly approximate the number of solutions to $a^2+b^2+c^2\leq R^2$ since the lattice points are "uniformly distributed" in space. The problem is that this says nothing about the (approximate) number of solutions to the equality $a^2+b^2+c^2=R^2$.

Comment: The number of solutions on one sphere oscillates wildly. You can't really approximate it.